# What exactly does "attach context" mean in Eclipse Mylyn

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

the mylyn plugin in Eclipse (Trac connector) contains the option to attach and then retrive the "context" of an issue. Attaching the context results in attaching a zipped XML file to the issue entry in the Trac system. However, I don't quite understand what is this context is. Initially I thought that this was all the opened files and cursor positions in those files. But apparently I was wrong. Searching the net did not help.

Comment: There's doc now up at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn_User_Guide for this feature.

Answer (score 20):

The Mylyn context is a collection of "landmarks" in your code.  A "landmark" is a source file or method, or resource file that is "interesting" (typically means you have opened it when task was active).  This article on Mylyn [Mylyn 2.0, Part 2: Automated context management](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mylyn2/) may help clear up any confusion on what a context is.

Sharing the context should allow others to see what parts of the code you have been viewing.  If you are having issues sharing a context, the Mylyn FAQ on [Team support](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn_FAQ#Team_Support) may help.

Comment: This isn't quite true (anymore - it very well may have been right in 2008).  Landmark is a category that's above interesting now.  Think of landmark as something like interesting++, but you can also mark it yourself.  Visiting something usually makes it interesting, but it can fall off the list.  Marking it as a landmark (on a Mac, the default acrobatic key combo is ctrl-shift-option-command-upArrow.  Really.) will keep it as a landmark.  Landmarks are usually indicated by something like bolding.